# JSON to DataTable net with varing roots

Tags: json, vb.net

This is my first dealing with `JSON` and unfortunately I have to do it in `VB.Net`, company policy. So I have searched high and low and tried a lot of examples even converted some of the `C#` code to `VB.Net` but I can't seem to find a complete solution.

I receive a `JSON` string like this:

```vb
{
   "65080007":{
      "partNo":"ATD000007",
      "description":"Swingarm Hat Platform",
      "quantity":4,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080143":{
      "partNo":"ATD000143",
      "description":"ASY Gas Spring Bracket",
      "quantity":2,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080071":{
      "partNo":"ATD000071",
      "description":"TT Gas Spring",
      "quantity":2,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080147":{
      "partNo":"ATD000147",
      "description":"ASY Lateral Hinge",
      "quantity":8,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65085181":{
      "partNo":"RD0181",
      "description":"ASY KIT Bolt, Carriage, 0.375 in x 16, 1.5 in (x45) & Nut, Flange, 0.375 in x 16 (x45)",
      "quantity":1,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080796":{
      "partNo":"ATD000796",
      "description":"Decal, TT Equipped, Rectangular, 5 in x 10 in",
      "quantity":1,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080797":{
      "partNo":"ATD000797",
      "description":"Decal, TT Open/Close, Triangular, 12 in x 8 in",
      "quantity":1,
      "assemblyseq":""
   },
   "65080745":{
      "partNo":"ATD000745",
      "description":"",
      "quantity":1,
      "assemblyseq":""
   }
}
```

What I need to do bind or assign this data to a `DataGridView.DataSource`.
I've seen some examples but I can't set it as a `DataSource`.
I've tried this example:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim json_result = GetJson()
    Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json_result, (DataTable))
    Dim newJString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

    Console.WriteLine("Re-serialized JSON: ")
    Console.WriteLine(newJString)
    Console.WriteLine("")
End Sub

Public Function GetJson() As String
    Dim json_result As String = <![CDATA[
    ' I used the above json string
    Return json_result
End Function
```

I have made my `JSON` classes to deserialise the `JSON` and tried `JsonConvert.Deserialize` keep getting an error it epected a array and found an object.

```vb
Public Class Jobs
    '<JsonProperty("partno")>
    Public Property PartNo As String
    ' <JsonProperty("description")>
    Public Property Description As String
    '<JsonProperty("quantity")>
    Public Property Quantity As String
    '<JsonProperty("assemblyseq")>
    Public Property Assemblyseq As String
End Class
```

The issue I think is the root properties `"65080797"` these numbers will not be the same every time we get the `JSON` back from `NetSuite`.

So I tried to:

```vb
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Jobs)(result)
Console.WriteLine(obj.PartNo) it comes out PartNo = nothing
```

So I've tried this:

```vb
Dim resultA = JsonUtil.Deserialize(Of Jobs)(result, ignoreRoot:=True)
Module JsonUtil
    Function Deserialize(Of T As Class)(ByVal json As String, ByVal ignoreRoot As Boolean) As T
    Return If(ignoreRoot, JObject.Parse(json)?.Properties()?.First()?.Value?.ToObject(Of T)(), JObject.Parse(json)?.ToObject(Of T)())
    End Function
End Module
```

This gives me the first group:

```vb
ATD000007
Swingarm Hat Platform
4
```

The assembly number was blank.
I'm open for any suggestions on how I can get the above `JSON` into a data table or DataGridView or how to make a list without the root  `"65080797"` this number will be unique with every response.
The people that designed this response string refuses to remove the root properties.

Thank you for taking the time to read this mess.
All comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: [Use an online parser/builder](https://app.quicktype.io?share=NlS8ik5feK0jiLOReOs0). The class is generated in C#, but you have just  some properties to convert.

Comment: How do you expect the DGV to deal with the keys ("65080007")? It doesnt do groups  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Json array looks like [something] instead of {somthing}, you could convert it to array if you want but you can also do it in different ways and even without any external library, you could create a datatable then bind it to datagridview or you could add data directly to datagridview.

Anyway, I made a datatable for you.

```
    Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization 'for reading of JSON (+add the reference to System.Web.Extensions library)
    Dim JSONC = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)))(JSON) 'you could do it in different ways too
    Dim NewDT As New DataTable
    'Create Columns
    For Each key In JSONC.First.Value.Keys 
    '"65080007" <first
    '{ "partNo":"ATD000007", "description":"Swingarm Hat Platform", "quantity":4, "assemblyseq":"" } <first.value
    ' "partNo" <first.value.key(s) :"ATD000007" <first.value.value(s) 
        NewDT.Columns.Add(key)
    Next
    'Add Rows
    For Each item In JSONC
        NewDT.Rows.Add(item.Value.Values.ToArray)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = NewDT
```

[image]

Comment: I tried both answer and they both worked I selected this one as the answer because it was the first one I used. But both CruleD and ScheuNZ answer will work for this issue. Thank you I appreciate the explanation without sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unusually structured JSON like that, your best bet is probably to resort to using raw JObject and JToken handling instead of trying to get JSON.NET to deserialize into structured data automatically.

Create a method that will convert an individual JToken into the Job class you described in your question. I've added a Key property to identify those unique keys in the JSON that were problematic for you; if you don't need these, just remove the .Key bit from the example below.

```
Public Function CreateJob(data As JToken)
    Return New Job With
    {
        .Key = data.Path,
        .PartNo = data("partNo"),
        .Description = data("description"),
        .Quantity = data("quantity"),
        .Assemblyseq = data("assemblyseq")
    }
End Function
```

Once you have Job objects being created, you can walk the entire structure and turn it into an array of jobs with the sample code below.

```
Dim result As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
Dim jobs As Job() = result.Values().Select(Of Job)(AddressOf CreateJob).ToArray()
```

Once you have an array of Job objects, binding to a DataSource should be trivial.

Comment: Your answer work also!!Thank you I appreciate the explanation without sarcasm.